Image preloading does not have an effect
I'm working on a website with quite poor LCP (around 5-6 seconds according to PageSpeed). And I was tasked with improving it. After taking a look at networking tab I saw that the browser first loads bunch of JS and CSS (a lot of them), and only then it loads the image that we need for LCP. But then, after loading all JS and CSS, browser still stalls for some unknown to me reason, preventing the image from being downloaded for even longer:

This is a Nuxt app, so almost all this JS and CSS files are various chunks of the app or separate components. There are also some other 3rd party stuff.
I figured that if I will move the LCP image somewhere higher in the queue it should do the trick. And to achieve this I've done couple of things:

I've added <link rel="preconnect" href="https://assets.mydomain.com">
I've added <link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://assets.mydomain.com/myphoto">
I've added fetchpriority="high" to the preload above

But each of these steps does not fully work...
First of all, the preconnect thing seems to not do anything. I would expect that the DNS lookup will disappear from the waterfall, since my assumption is that if browser is preconnected to that domain, it shouldn't be related to any of the images. But it is still there, right before loading of an image. And overall it behaves strangely. Sometimes it is there on the first image, sometimes it is on some other images later in the queue. There no pattern there. And even if one image is queued much earlier it looks like all of them are waiting for the same DNS lookup and SSL to finish before starting downloading. Why is that?
In the example below DNS lookup is assigned to the last image (the pink part represents DNS + SSL):

Next there is an issue with preload. On the face of it, it seems to be working. It puts up the image as the second thing in the queue. But the image itself is still hanging in "Queueing" or "Stalled" for a very long time. And it still begins downloading with all the other images as before. So it actually made no difference.

Then I tried adding fetchpriority="high" to the preload. It seems it made some difference. From time to time (not always) the preloaded image seems to not wait for other images and it is loaded quicker:

But it still not very stable. For example on the above screenshot there is no DNS lookup anywhere. Preloaded image is loaded faster than the rest. But after page refresh it can happen, that the DNS lookup will again be there and all the images will be again blocked by it:

But anyway, preloading works only on Chrome, and it is not working on Firefox. Actually on Firefox, after all this steps, the image is now set a the LOWEST priority:

I'm lost for words honestly. The same website opened on Chrome treats this image with high priority, while Firefox as the lowest. It makes me feel like there is a bug in Firefox regarding either preload or fetchpriority...
And I'm a bit stuck at this point. Browser behavior is not stable and seems like a complete magic, without any connection to my code. Do you have any ideas what I could do here? At the very least make is so that the LCP metric is reasonable.
One side note in the end, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm testing things out on localhost right now. So apart from the first screenshot all the others are from locally hosted wewbsite.
